# Devise, merge guest and user session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is there a way to hook into signin process (using devise), to merge "guest" session data before signing in, and some other data (Mysql) after signin in?

For example I need to merge user's cart data from session, when he goes to ordering step and logs in, and already has items in DB

Found some solutions here, but I don't want to create guest users in DB, just need to merge sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a bit hacky, but you could do it in the `after_sign_in_path_for` controller method.

```
class ApplicationController

  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    merge_cart_from session[:cart]  # or whatever
    root_path
  end

end
```